# Jersey serializing null values to json : How to skip

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey 2.4 with spring.

When I am returning a response from a method with an annotation `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` on it, it also serialize the null values to json.

I don't want to serialize the fields that contains the null values.

Is there any solution for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you are using Jackson for serialization, you can use the `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` to your class to exclude the null values.

Comment: I have tried adding this annotation, but its not working.

Comment: @SAM: Which library are you using for serialization?

Comment: I am using a dependency of jersey-media-json-jackson and '<dependency>
  <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
  <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>'
</dependency>

Comment: I have also registered `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class` with my Jersey application, then this annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) `started working.